# Django error : takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to set up django on an EC2 ubuntu instance.

In my view I have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
import requests


def test(request):
    return HttpResponse('hi')
```

urls.py have:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'tp.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^index/$', 'tp1.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^test/$', 'tp1.views.test', name='test'),    

    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I'm getting the error above. What am I doing wrong?

edit;

```
 Environment:    


 Request Method: GET
 Request URL: http://52.10.**-**:8000/test/  

 Django Version: 1.7.5
 Python Version: 3.4.0
 Installed Applications:
 ('django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'tp1')
 Installed Middleware:
 ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')  


 Traceback:
 File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
   111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)  

 Exception Type: TypeError at /test/
 Exception Value: test() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Are there any additional parameters in browser? i mean something like `127.0.0.1:8000/test/some_thing`. it seems error is about this. [edit: they are right. full traceback d be better]

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Is that the full error message? What takes 0 positional arguments? Hmmmm....

Comment: The little code that there is looks perfectly fine. Can you tell us if your code runs without error on your local dev machine? This will help us better understand if the issue is directly correlated to your ubuntu server configuration.

Comment: OK, the problem in this case was that my code changes were not being picked up by the server ( in this case nginx ), so after each change I should have been restarting uwsgi and nginx

Answer (score 1):

The code in your question looks fine, but the `test()` view function takes *one* positional argument (`request`), so the code in your question is not the code that raised that exception.

Did you leave out any code (maybe you re-defined `test` later in the `views.py` file)?  Is that code at the top from `tp1/views.py` or some other file?

Answer (score 0):

in this code:

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'tp.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^index/$', 'tp1.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^test/$', 'tp1.views.test', name='test'),    

    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

change the brackets into square brackets:

```
urlpatterns = patterns['',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'tp.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^index/$', 'tp1.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^test/$', 'tp1.views.test', name='test'),    

    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```